# Ref.Current is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

TLDR - I need help figuring out how to change a subcomponent color using refs.

I'm trying to teach myself a little more about React refs by doing a simple example: **comparing a background color change in subcomponents with both props and refs.** I realize this is not a best practice in the wild, however, for a toy example, it seemed like a good isolated exercise.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import SubComponent1 from './SubComponent1'
import SubComponent2 from './SubComponent2'

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let myRef = React.createRef();

    return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <SubComponent1
                  message = "Passing via props"
                  color = "orange"
              />
              <SubComponent2
                  message = "Passing via ref" 
                  ref={myRef}
              />
              {console.log("hi")}
              {console.log(myRef)}
            {console.log(myRef.current)}
            {/*{myRef.current.style = { backgroundColor: 'green' }}*/}
          </header>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I would like to be able to call myRef.current.style = { backgroundColor: 'green' } (or something to that effect) in my App.js file, however, it seems like myRef.current is null when I try to call it.

When I console log, I get {current : null}, but upon expanding, the component data is there. I read this may be because myRef.current gets wiped after compomentDidMount, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

[image]

If I wanted to go about completing this example, what would be the best way for me to do so? Ideally, I think I'd like to be able to call the line I have commented out or something like it.

Code - https://github.com/ericadohring/ReactRef

Comment: Move your createRef function outside render, because it will be cleared and filled with every render. https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define the ref variable in component, not under the render function.

```
component ... {
     myRef = React.createRef();
...
render() {
...
...
}
}
```